# Entity Framework How to generate PrimaryKey by mask

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to generate a primary key by mask (for example: `BS{100-999}-{Rand(100-999)}`) But I do not know how to generate a key like this in EF code/ Could somebody help me please to figure this out?

My model:

```
[Table("Tickets")]
public class Ticket
{
    public Ticket()
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        LastChangeDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        UserReviewed = true;
        EmailAlert = true;
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } //now it is Guid But i need this to be string and generated by the above mask
    public string UsersName { get; set; }
    public string Theme { get; set; }
    public string Request { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string TypeMask { get; set; }
    public string StatusMask { get; set; }
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    public bool EmailAlert { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
    public bool UserReviewed { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TicketRecord> Answers { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StatusMask")]
    public virtual TicketStatus Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TypeMask")]
    public virtual TicketType Type { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SenderId")]
    public virtual UserProfile Sender { get; set; }
    public virtual AttachmentsCollection IncludedFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to mapping the key? or how can you make the sequence?

Comment: @Jorge I am asking how to make EF generate a new unique key when I add a record using my pattern

Comment: You need to define your mapping with the key, the only thing that `EF` it's going to do for you it's generated the constraint in the Database, and `sql` needed to insert the value but nothing else

Comment: @Jorge Could you describe this in more details please or provide me with a link on how to do this, since I am very new to EF and not fully understand what you are talking about... Thank you!

Comment: ok, but first show me the model (Your POCO Class)

Comment: But you just need to remove `[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and create your custom method to create your key

Comment: @Jorge that's what I can not understand... How to generate it so that it would be guaranteed unique?

Answer (score 0):

EF never generates keys. Either you need to generate the key by yourself or you let the EF know that the key will be generated by the database using StoreGeneragedPattern annotation/setting. EF cannot generate keys as it cannot guarantee uniquenesses for the generated values.